# SQL: Remove part of the string from all the entries returned by the SELECT statement

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012

The following is the select statement that returns all the URL's containing a *%20* (space) at the end of it:

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 like '%%20'
```

How can the '*%20*' be removed from all these URLs using SQL?

**Edit 1:**

Is there a way to remove '*%20*' only if it is found in the end of the URL (saving all other instances on '*%20*' in the URL)?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? String functions vary. That probably isn't how to escape `%` in it also.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Your select statement returns all the URLs having `20` at the end. [MSDN: LIKE – Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx#Using%20Wildcard%20Characters%20As%20Literals)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is simple. I assume that you are using Microsoft SQL Server. Try the following:

```
 Select SUBSTRING(Column1,  0, Len(Column1) - 2) As Column1, Column2 
 From Table1 where Column1 like '%[%]20'
```

In above, I've selected Column1 and %20 will be removed from the end of Column1 and selected Column2 as well. You can select all your columns.

Comment: `where Column1 like '%%20'` is the same as `where Column1 like '%20'`. In SQL Server you can use `where Column1 like '%[%]20'` to match a percent literally.

Comment: @YashSaraiya - I'm glad :)

Comment: Note that this will replace %20 everywhere, not just at the end.

Comment: @YashSaraiya - Updated my answer.  It will replace %20 from the end only.

Comment: Thanks! I used this query for Dremio. The only thing I had to change is len() to char_length() as len() is not supported.

Answer (score 6):

```
  Select REPLACE(Column1,'%20','') From Table1 where Column1 like '%%20'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cut your field removing the last 3 characters when your field contains "%20":

```
select SUBSTR(Column1 ,0,LENGTH(Column1)-3 ) from Table1 where Column1 like '%%20'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.